# Node js Puppeteer goto array of youtube links to screenshot images

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to go to youtube, login then go into video links to take a screen shot.

But I get this error.I have read other similar quesiton and I have done what they suggested: Use a forloop. Please dont duplicate label this.

```
(node:18337) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 response listeners added.
```

Here is my code. This is what I am tring to do.

```
var proccessALink = async (link,label)=>{
    if (validUrl.isWebUri(urlToScreenshot)) {
      ;(async () => {
        await page.goto(link, {
          waitUntil: 'networkidle'
        })
        const video = await page.$('.html5-video-player')
        await page.evaluate(() => {
          // Hide youtube player controls.
          let dom = document.querySelector('.ytp-chrome-bottom')
          dom.style.display = 'none'
        })
        await video.screenshot({path: downloadPath});
      })()
    } else {
      res.send('Invalid url: ' + urlToScreenshot)
    }

  }
  for(let i = 0; i<linksArr.length; i++){
      var link = linksArr[i];
      var label = labelsArr[i];
      await proccessALink(link, label) 
  }
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a **warning**

Comment: Is this code not working? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: @OT413, First the error ```(node:18337) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 response listeners added.``` is thrown .Then error ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Cannot find context with specified id undefined  ``` is returned